# To alter column not null and default valu in sql using xml file

Tags: sql, xml

I want to add a constraint not null to an existing column and also a default value: true.

The existing column is:

```
<changeSet author="manuela" id="20200618150100-2">
    <addColumn tableName="proposition_affaire">
        <column defaultValueBoolean="true"
                name="mail_usage_nom"
                type="bit"/>
    </addColumn>
</changeSet>
```

At first, I was thinking that this would be sufficient but it's not.Indeed, as expected, the previous rows were filled with this defaultValue, but the new created ones are not and the value is set to null.

I tried the following but it's not working (it does not change anything):

```
 <changeSet author="manuela" id="20200716150700-1">
        <addNotNullConstraint  columnDataType="bit"
                               columnName="mail_vouvoiement"
                               defaultNullValue="true"
                               tableName="proposition_affaire"/>
        <addNotNullConstraint  columnDataType="bit"
                               columnName="mail_usage_nom"
                               defaultNullValue="false"
                               tableName="proposition_affaire"/>
    </changeSet>
```

In this try, the defaultValue is not accepted because it's a string in a boolean column.

How can I add not null constraint on this column and force the default value using change set xml?
I also need to change the defaultValueBoolean to false for one of my column.

Thanks,

Manuela

Comment: Hi Manuela. The SQL tag under your question; please hover your mouse over it, read the whole tooltip text... then apply what the tooltip's message is conveying.

Answer (score 0):

Try next:

```
<changeSet author="manuela" id="20200618150100-2">
    <addColumn tableName="proposition_affaire">
        <column defaultValueBoolean="true" name="mail_usage_nom" type="bit">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
    </addColumn>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).